# When is the polynomial $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\,\left(x-a_i\right)+1$ reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, ring-theory

This post is inspired by [Prove that the polynomial $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\,\left(x-a_i\right)-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1845213/prove-that-a-polynomial-function-is-irreducible/).

> (A) Find all positive integers $n$ and integers $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ such that $a_1< a_2 < \ldots < a_n$ and that the polynomial
>   $$f(x):=\left(x-a_1\right)\left(x-a_2\right)\cdots\left(x-a_n\right)+1$$
>   is a reducible element of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (or equivalently, of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$).

To prove (A), one attempt is to show that $f(x)$ can not be a perfect square.  Hence, it is natural to ask the following related problem (B).

> (B) Find all positive integers $n$ and integers $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ such that $a_1 \leq  a_2 \leq \ldots \leq a_n$ and that the polynomial
>   $$f(x):=\left(x-a_1\right)\left(x-a_2\right)\cdots\left(x-a_n\right)+1$$
>   is a perfect square in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (or equivalently, in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$).

While I have solutions to (A) and (B), I don't yet have a solution to the problem (C) given below.

> (C) Find all positive integers $n$ and integers $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ such that $a_1 \leq  a_2 \leq \ldots \leq a_n$ and that the polynomial
>   $$f(x):=\left(x-a_1\right)\left(x-a_2\right)\cdots\left(x-a_n\right)+1$$
>   is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (or equivalently, in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$).

I also don't have a solution to this modified version (D) of the link above.

> (D) Find all positive integers $n$ and integers $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ such that $a_1 \leq  a_2 \leq \ldots \leq a_n$ and that the polynomial
>   $$f(x):=\left(x-a_1\right)\left(x-a_2\right)\cdots\left(x-a_n\right)-1$$
>   is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (or equivalently, in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$).

Even more generally, we have this seemingly monstrously difficult problem (E).

> (E) For given $u\in\mathbb{N}$ and $v\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $\gcd(u,v)=1$, find all integers $n$ and integers $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ such that $a_1 \leq  a_2 \leq \ldots \leq a_n$ and that the polynomial
>   $$f(x):=u\left(x-a_1\right)\left(x-a_2\right)\cdots\left(x-a_n\right)+v$$
>   is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (or equivalently, in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$).

If (E) seems too difficult, it may make sense to try when $u$ and $|v|$ are perfect $k$-th powers for some integer $k>1$, when $u$ and $v$ are prime integers or $\pm 1$, or when $a_1<a_2<\ldots<a_n$ is assumed.

---

I know that this post is loaded with multiple questions.  However, as they are very closely related, I don't think it hurts to place them in the same thread.

**P.S.** Part (A) already has an answer here: [Proving that a polynomial of the form $(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_n) + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1304679/proving-that-a-polynomial-of-the-form-x-a-1-cdotsx-a-n-1-is-irreducible?rq=1).

Comment: We again get that $f(x)=((x-b_1)\ldots(x-b_{n/2})+1)((x-b_{n/2+1})\ldots(x-b_n)-1)=(p(x)+1)(q(x)-1)$, so $q(x)-2=p(x)$

Comment: @bigant146 Yes, for Part (A), that is a good start.